# How to select an object from (this) Jquery

Tags: jquery

i cant sellect an object from (This)

```
<dd class="EachMovie">
  <a href="LINK">
     <img src="IMAGE" />
     <span class="TitulodoPost">TITLE</span>
     <br>
     <span id="idioma">EXAMPLE</span>
  </a>
  <div class="cat-STATIC-DATA"></div>
</dd>
```

I'm using this function

```
$(".EachMovie").each(function(){
 var texto = $(this ".TitulodoPost").height(); // This is whong
 var classe = $(this).find("div").css("height","600px"); // This is OK                       
});
```

How can select the .TitulodoPost in the loop ??

Comment: The `<div>` is outside of the `<span>`, so that will not work. You would have to select the `<div>` that is inside the `<dd>` tag unless you set an id for the div tag that will be static

Comment: I change the code, now the div is inside the EachMovie ..

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).closest("dd").find("div");
```

This assumes that the div is the only div inside the `dd`.  If you control the html here, I would add a static class to the div to make it easier to target consistently.

Comment: Thank you, but i now i cant select the other value... How can i use this?? $(this ".TitulodoPost").height(); seems like this way generate an error .. i try $(this + ".TitulodoPost").height(); too

Comment: @user758499 You can't concatenate an object with a string for generating a selector.

Comment: So how can i select the class TitulodoPost inside the object in the loop?

Comment: @user758499 You would do it in the same way.  `$(this).find(".TitulodoPost")`